# CodeIgniter Wanwizard DM Join other field

Tags: codeigniter, left-join, codeigniter-datamapper

Tables

Upload Fields

```
id|user_id|link|status
```

Upload_acc Fields

```
id|user_id|name|password
```

Upload Acc Model

```
var $table = 'Upload';
var $has_one = array(
'Upload_acc'=>array('class'=>'Upload_acc','other_field'=>'upload','join_table'=>'Upload_acc'),
);
```

How do I make this query with dm?

```
SELECT * FROM Upload LEFT JOIN Upload_acc ON Upload.user_id = Upload_acc.user_id WHERE Upload.status=0
```

I looked I could not find [document](http://datamapper.wanwizard.eu/pages/advancedrelations.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't.

Datamapper is an ORM which maintains relations between objects on primary key. You can not (mis)use it as a glorified query builder.

You can create a custom method in your Upload model, run a standard AR query in it using $this->db, and feel the result to $this->process_query(). This will convert the result of your custom query into Datamapper objects.